# Deploy application to iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, deployment, simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install iPhone application in iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator)

I am looking for a way to deploy my application to another users simulator. To be blunt the person needs to show the application on the simulator and is not capable of compiling the source code and I don't have the time to produce the instructions.

What I want to do is provide them with the .app (or another) file and have them install it in the simulator just like they can do with any real iPhone Device.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If they are not capable of compiling the source code, I highly doubt that they are capable of installing it in the simulator, for which you would also need to provide the instructions and support them.

Maybe you could do screensharing with them to show it to them on your own simulator? Or send them a video or screencast of the app being used?