# Install iOS app into xcode simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcodebuild

We're iOS (and other mobile platform) developers and our sales folks routinely need to provide demos of our apps for clients. What we're trying to do is automate a process so sales people can go to a self-serve website and feed the app into their simulator.

Using xcodebuild we can kick off the build process and then present it as a secure download link (via our intranet) but all that lets them do is install it to their iOS device. This is OK except not everyone on the road has an iOS device (or some have old iPod touches, and that's super slow). So, I was thinking that there's gotta be a way to get it installed in their simulator.

I see that others have hacked it in there by zipping up a simulator directory and placing it on another:
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=7680994

> Set target to simulator, release. 
>   deploy. stop iphone simulator. zip
>   your app from ~/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/User/Applications/   send it
>   to someone else, and let that person
>   know to unzip it in that folder, than
>   start iphone simulator - and you're
>   done.

I guess we can do this, but it doesn't seem deterministic (or at least, a lot harder to script). I'd prefer to work with the .app but if the only way to do it is with this hacky copy and paste operation, that'll be what we have to do.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's primarily a function of Apple's restrictive device positioning scheme. Even then, it's still a PITA to install the bins on the devices that we do have. It's easier (comparatively) to install it on simulator.

Answer (score 4):

This could work: https://github.com/landonf/simlaunch/

I have not tried it yet by myself, but from video looks like the application converts .app compiled for simulator to a launcher, which can be used to run the app in simulator without installing it through xcode.

It probably uses the same kind of approach for simulating the app without installing it first that is described here: [How to install iPhone application in iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator)

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but have you thought about having a server (eg a Mac mini) that has all the installed software on it? Then they could just use some form of screen sharing to run the app remotely.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We do have a Mac mini (that's our build server). Unfortunately, most of the time on the road they don't have access to internet (especially on client sites, where there may be no cell service or locked-down WiFi), so that wouldn't really work. Buying a personal cell wifi would be more expensive than buying everyone iPod Touch(es) :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used the simulator build mechanism above with a number of clients and once they figure out the right folder to drop the actual folder into, it's gone very well.

It's a little bit of a hack as you say but in some cases it also beats having to deal with ad hoc provisioning etc when it's less important to have it on an actual device itself.

I haven't tried it yet but I've heard pretty good things about Test Flight (http://testflightapp.com/) also as a way to distribute demos/betas so that might be worth a look as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just developed a pair of scripts to (a) extract an app from a iOS simulator, and (b) install it on another iOS simulator. https://github.com/christopher-prince/SimAppScripts

Answer (score 1):

Locate the `.app` bundle in your built products directory, typically under `Debug-iphonesimulator` or `Release-iphonesimulator`. Drag and drop that bundle onto the Simulator window and it will be installed (you may need to swipe on the home screen to show the icon).

You can also script this from the command line using `xcrun simctl install`. The `xcrun simctl launch` command can also start the application.

Most build systems can be automated (or you can use a post-build script from within Xcode, ordered as the last step) to create a ZIP of the app bundle and put it somewhere for download.

(If having the Archive workflow support creating Simulator IPAs would be useful for you please file an enhancement request at https://bugreport.apple.com)

Answer (score 0):

check out waxsim:

https://github.com/square/WaxSim

http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2011/12/running-your-ios-app-in-the-simulator-from-the-command-line.html

If you build it for i386 and distribute the .app, I believe this will work.

Comment: does not work with iOS7. Definitely not with iOS8 / Mac10.10.