# iOS simulate Application and log events

Tags: iphone, ios, security, emulation

I want to install and simulate iOS applications and find their malware intentions. See if connects to an IP address, downloads something, API call logs and soo on... kind of everything it does on the system. Does iOS Simulator log this events, or is there any online project that does that. If not then I should do it from scratch, do you have any advice how to do this?  I only have the application file, not the entire Xcode project.

ALL i have is a bunch of applications(not the projects) that i have to test. All i want is to run them and log their actions in an automated way. Just like running a windows application on a virtual machine and log api trace, internet connections, memory, registry, disk actions... IN AN AUTOMATED WAY.

Thank you.

Comment: iOS applications can't send SMSes.

Comment: Where are you getting these apps? If they're from the app store they are safe and you can't run them on a computer anyway.  It sounds like you are just getting shady compiled apps off of the internet.

Comment: All i want is to run them and log their actions in an automated way. malware or not.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS simulator apps simply run on Mac, but their output is shown in the iOS simulator. This means that any tool that allows you to audit Mac applications will allow you to do the same with the iOS simulator.

Check your Activity Monitor, you'll see that the app is simply listed there. I think the standard Xcode Instruments will work fine for you.

Comment: Hi Tom... I suspect the guy asking the question is asking for the ability to install any and ***all*** applications into the simulator, probably even ones from the store.  Not just applications he himself wrote.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann That's not what he asked though. If he really wants that he should probably build his own simulator.

Comment: Michael Dautermann you are right their not my applications their are from the store.

Comment: @user1119250 Then use your iOS device to test it instead of the sim. However, I'm pretty sure that Apple tests the applications pretty well.

Comment: If they are from the store I would not be too concerned about security threats.

Comment: All i want is to run them and log their actions in an automated way. malware or not.Thank you.

Comment: @user1119250 You cannot install applications from the store in the simulator.

Comment: i didn't say that i want to install them on the simulator, just install and run them on enything tha emulates IOS that will allow me to log the app actions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Xcode project, then look at the code and the debugger while it is running.  Other than that, if you run it in the iOS simulator you will only see the GUI portion of the app, unless you are running it side by side from Xcode (then you can use Instruments or the debugger).  [This documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator) should allow you to run the apps on the simulator.

Comment: all a have is a bunch of applications(not the projects) that ia have to test. All i want is to run them and log their actions in an automated way.

Comment: Edited with helpful link (see above)