# Can I install the "app store" in an IOS simulator?

Tags: ios, app-store, simulator

The IOS simulator in my computer doesn't have app store.  I want to use the app store to test a program I wrote on my simulator.

Is it possible to install the app store in my simulator?

Comment: To test your app in the simulator, open the project in Xcode and click the run button in the top right corner.

Comment: This is an unusual request.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @MDT I don't mean to test a normal app. In the app I write, it will open another app link in appstore.

Comment: @borrrden install a app store in the simulator, like the real iphone or ipad

Comment: @William This is something that you should probably be testing on a real device.

Comment: See also: [Can the App Store be installed on Xcode's iOS Simulator on the new ARM/M1 powered Macs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408084)

Comment: can we install apps from other developers? I want to test deep linking into another app (metamask) so it would be helpful on-device.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

**This is NOT possible**

The Simulator does not run **ARM** code, ONLY **x86** code. Unless you have the raw source code from Apple, you won't see the App Store on the Simulator.

The app you write you will be able to test in the Simulator by running it directly from Xcode even if you don't have a developer account. To test your app on an actual device, you will need to be a part of the [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/) program.

Comment: So if I need to know weather my app can open the appstore properly or not, I have to test it in real device?

Comment: Yes, if you are going to have your app open the App Store, then you would want to test it on an actual device.

Comment: We can't install app store apps in simulator. This is updated link of apple doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator.html

Comment: @Rohit link is dead

Comment: Quick search turns up this updated guide on the Simulator: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: And what about on an ARM-powered Mac?

Comment: It correct that it's not possible, but the reason why it's not possible turns out to have nothing to do with Intel x86 code vs ARM code, as [it's also not possible on Apple's new M1 ARM macs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/408129/11513).

Comment: I assume this is out of date now that we have M1 macs? don't they run the same object code as iPhones?

Comment: @dcsan good point, but I think Apple intentionally doesn't want the iOS app store app running on anything other an an iOS device. Alternatively, they may have made available all of the iOS apps in the Mac app store as well, or will eventually once all intel machines are phased out.

Comment: you can install many iOS apps on desktop. i'm not sure if one has to add an extra target at dev time tho

Answer (score 26):

No, according to Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH3-SW8):

> Note: You cannot install apps from the App Store in simulation environments.

Comment: The link here and in the comments on WrightsCS answer all go to the base "Simulator Help" page now, so pretty much not helpful.

Answer (score 7):

You can install other builds but not Appstore build.

From **Xcode 8.2**,drag and drop the build to simulator for the installation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41671233/1522584