# Can i test an app store link in the ios simulator?

Tags: app-store, ios-simulator

I working on the LITE version of my app. The link page to the full version seems to work on my devices but not on the simulator? Is that normal? Do I need to set an option on the simulator to allow web calls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The App Store app does not exist in the simulator, so you can only test it on an actual device.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611146/can-i-install-the-app-store-in-an-ios-simulator) for more info.