# Xamarin iPad simulator for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

My app was rejected by Apple for not looking okay on the iPad. It is an iPhone app, but they require it to run on the iPad as well. I am using Visual Studio for developing the app.

The problem is that I don't have a recent iPad for testing so I want to test in the simulator.  However, if I want to select the deployment target, the iPad devices are listed as unsupported. 
The only way I can run it on the iPad is if I change the iOS Application Target to Universal, but then it doesn't scale as an iPhone app anymore. I can't change the Device in the Simulator on the Mac after the app has been deployed because that will just start an instance of the iPad which is totally seperate from the iPhone simulator.

Couldn't find anything here or in the forums at Xamarin. So I'm kind of stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to test this scenario on the simulator. This is the same in Xcode as it will not allow you to select the iPad simulators when the app is only built for iPhone. Xamarin Studio / Xamarin.VisualStudio matches this behaviour, so this is not a bug.

You might be able to install the app manually to the iPad simulator - take a look at this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28387749/451678

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know if it Is possible to use a real iPad or is this also not possible?

Comment: It should be possible to use a real iPad if I recall from my previous experience (though that was a while ago now!). Again, if it isn't possible you can load the app on your device manually to test.

Comment: It would probably work to install the package manually however I cannot seem to create a valid package using a iPhoneSimulator configuration.
From what I understand it is not possible to use an ipa because the binaries of the simulator and the device are completely different.

When I build using ad-hoc/enterrise package for the iPhoneSimulator I get an empty plist and binary.

Comment: I can confirm it does work on a real iPad btw. I have an old iPad 2 on which the app works. But it also looks okay, so cannot reproduce the problem on it, so I'm still stuck. The issue probably only exists on a retina device, so I still need the simulator for this or I need to buy a retina iPad, which sucks bigtime...

Comment: @RobHouweling Yes you would need to build for iPhone to produce an ARM binary rather than iPhoneSimualtor which will build i386 / x86_64. Unfortunately I do not see a way of directly deploying an iPhone only app to the iPad simulator from XS as we use the toolchain as Xcode (which does the same thing). You should be able to build the app for iPhoneSimulator then install it as linked in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. The problem is that I can't seem to produce a valid build using iPhoneSimulator. I get a folder in the Release (depends on configuration used) containing 2 empty files, a info.plist and a file named after the bundle id.