# Can't install app in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm trying to run a simple app written in Swift with Xcode 9 Beta (9M136h).

For some reasons the app could not be installed, I get stuck in the "installing" phase within the simulator.

[image]

Comment: Did you try resetting simulator?

Comment: I tried that several times, also restarting xcode. Note that my app is just sample app has nothing special.

Comment: Give it a try with terminal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28387749/8017437

Comment: Worked fine from terminal, but any thoughts why it's not working from xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Muhammad Hassan's comment , I managed to solve it this way :

In the menu at the top of the screen, I pressed '**Hardware**' and then '**Erase all Content and Settings**' fixe the issue for me. 
This will clear the entire simulator.

Then I did a clean, build and run.

Comment: When I said "Did you try resetting simulator", I meant that.

Answer (score 1):

Delete you app from the simulator.
Clean it (Command+shift+K).
Run it again.
Hope this will work.