# iOS debug installed app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

Is it possible to debug an application that I downloaded from the App Store on my iPhone device using xCode simulator?.
I am using xCode 8 and iOS 9.3 Simulator.

Comment: No you can't . Its not possible

Comment: You need source code and symbols both. The application which you download from the store do not give either of the thing.

Answer (score 0):

No, AppStore app are signed for production therefore all the debugs should be obfuscated and not accessible by third parties.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to install an app from AppStore in iOS simulator.

For further information, please check this link:

[Can I install the "app store" in an IOS simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611146/can-i-install-the-app-store-in-an-ios-simulator)