# Trying add install Spotify in Simulator swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, spotify

I am trying to install or drag and drop Spotify application on simulator , i have already install in mac but when i m trying to install in simulator show me error popUp

**Error:** This app could not be installed at this time.

**Screen Shot:**

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NOT possible

The Simulator does not run ARM code, ONLY x86 code. Unless you have the raw source code from Apple, you won't see the App Store on the Simulator.

The app you write you will be able to test in the Simulator by running it directly from Xcode even if you don't have a developer account. To test your app on an actual device, you will need to be apart of the Apple Developer program.

you can also check this One.
[Can I install the "app store" in an IOS simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611146/can-i-install-the-app-store-in-an-ios-simulator)

Comment: You do not need to be part of the Apple Developer program to test an App on a physical device.