# How to launch an iOS application in Simulator from Terminal and AppleScript

Tags: terminal, ios-simulator, applescript, .app

I have made an iOS application in Xcode and built it. It has created an `.app` bundle. I am able to launch the app in Simulator or on the device successfully from Xcode or iTunes, but now I want to launch it in Simulator through AppleScript from Terminal.

I am able to build the app from Terminal, but unable to launch it in Simulator. Somehow I found out that an `.ipa` file is needed to run the app from Terminal.

Is there a way to launch an iOS app I built in Simulator from Terminal?

Comment: i think there could be a way to install, load and run the app in to the simulator, as titanium sdk is able to perform the same from command line

Comment: This has been asked before on SO – you will find the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4894178/990363). Don’t forget to account for the fact the location of the iPhone Simulator has moved in Xcode 4.3 (since it is distributed as a single `.app` bundle via the App Store and cannot install external folder hierarchies anymore) – it’s found in `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/` now. Flagged as duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install iPhone application in iPhone Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

I found an .ipa file that I wanted using iTunes and copied it over to my desktop. After that I changed the extension to .zip and extracted it. Next I found the Payload folder and moved the application inside to my desktop. Finally I moved that application to my iPhone simulators applications folder found at: "Your disk name">Developer>Platforms>iPhoneSimulator.platform>Developer>SDKs> iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk>Applications

Hope this helps! (Note: Some apps crash more often than others.)