# Is it possible to install .app files onto the iPhone simulator without source

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, simulator, ipod

Is it possible to download and install raw .app files onto the iPhone simulator.  I like the functionality of some apps but simply do not have an iPhone.  Would it be possible to download the app files and install them onto the simulator?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator

Comment: Not really a duplicate, that question is asking how to run the project using xcode.

Comment: Most likely impossible since a real app is using arm code and the simulator is using i386 code. If you have something build for the Simulator, maybe you could figure out all the various files needed to make the Simulator see it and be happy. This is likely a lot of work but YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Release builds target ARM processors.  The simulator doesn't emulate the CPU, that's why you have to build for it specifically - simulator builds are x86.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean with the IPA file? Unfortunately with Ad Hoc releases you need to install the provisioning profile that AFAIK won't allow you to install. There may be a hack but without hacking it there is no way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If the developer is built for simulator arch, then you can run it. By placing the .app file in the following location.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/Applications/

Note: make sure your restarting the simulator to take effect.