# How do I run MonoTouch application in iOS Simulator from Terminal?

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, xamarin

Apparently, you can [start iOS app in Simulator from Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4894178/458193) by running

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication path_to_your_app/YourFavouriteApp.app/YourFavouriteApp
```

This does not work for a MonoTouch app—I'm getting a black Simulator screen.
How do I launch a compiled MonoTouch app in Simulator from Terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why it does not work. Maybe the simulator that will start up might not be the version you expect. You might want to check inside `Console.app` to see what went wrong.

Anyway you can use `mtouch` to start your application, e.g.

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --launchsim=/path/to/your/application.app
```

You can also specify which version of iOS to use and the device (iPhone or iPad) to start.
By default it runs on iPhone simulator. Adding `--device=2` flag will switch it to iPad.

See `mtouch` [man page](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=man%3amtouch%281%29) or `mtouch --help` for details.