# Is it possible to install Adobe reader or third party application in iOS simulator for testing?

Tags: iphone

I have tried to find out the answer in google. No luck . I'm using UIDocumentationController to open the PDF from my app. Its working fine in Device. I'm showing up with options to share adobe reader,etc. When i want to test it in iOS Simulator i don have option to open the PDf in Adobe reader. Could you please help me to install the third party apps in iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. Download the app from appstore. Downloaded app will be in your mac iTunes software
2. Right click the app file in iTunes and select show in finder will take you to the .ipa file location
3. Copy paste it in Desktop. Rightclick use some unarchive tool to unarchive it and it will give you the payload file.
4. Copy and paste it in this folder **Applications > Xcode.app (right click - Show Package Contents) > Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneSimulator.platform > SDKs > iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk > Applications**
5. Run your iOS Simulator. App will be there

Note: There is no guaranty that all the apps will work. There are lot of possibilities that the app can crash. That depends. Good luck with this

UPDATE:

There is another method also the simple way. Refer this for Terminal install

[How to install iPhone application in iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator)

Comment: I'm able to install the apps in iOS simulator. But as you said its not opening up. Its crashing.

Comment: This didn't work for me with Adobe Acrobat Reader on iPad2 / iOS 9.0 simulator (the app doesn't show in the list, event after a reboot)

Comment: When you download an app from the App Store, its meant to run on the ARM processor in physical iOS devices. The Simulator doesn't emulate that.

Comment: app binary downloaded from app store using iTunes is for physical device. It will not work on simulator