# Installing PDF reader in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, ios-simulator

Currently I am using Xcode 8.3.3 and Xcode 9 Beta 4.

How do I install a PDF reader and email apps in the iOS simulator.

I have gone through this link:
*[Is it possible to install Adobe reader or third party application in iOS simulator for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045788/is-it-possible-to-install-adobe-reader-or-third-party-application-in-ios-simulat)*

and

*[How to install iPhone application in iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator/41671233#41671233).

But it was of no use.

I even tried the drag and drop method. It shows the process, but then it displays the error "unable to install the app".

How do I add applications in simulators? Currently I don't have any devices, so I want to test the functionality on the simulator.

After trying a few options and going through some folders, I am confirmed that it can be done. Can it be done by placing the payload files of PDF viewers in iPhone simulator's application folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, [read these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045788/is-it-possible-to-install-adobe-reader-or-third-party-application-in-ios-simulat). However for me, the second step was not working. So I went for alternative method.

You need an iPhone for the above. If you don't have one, search the web for .ipa file of that apps and follow above procedure. Or you can use open source projects like: https://github.com/Alua-Kinzhebayeva/iOS-PDF-Reader.

Run this project for the first time. Go to project navigator:

[image]

Right click on the **PDFReader.app** and click "**Show in Finder**".

Copy and paste it in this folder `Applications > Xcode.app (right click - Show Package Contents) > Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneSimulator.platform > SDKs > iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk > Applications`.

and reboot the simulator. The app will be preinstalled like other apps in simulator. Ready enough to test your app functionality with pdf readers or any app you want.

Comment: Hi Amish. Please link to material on Stack Overflow, rather than copy+pasting large sections of it. Not only does this help with attribution (i.e. it helps you avoid charges of plagiarism) but it also ensures there are not multiple copies of the same material to keep maintained. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If it's an app *built for the simulator*, then yes it can be done using the methods you linked to.

If this is an app *built for the AppStore*, then it's not possible. Apps built for AppStore are compiled for ARM CPUs; for simulators, they're compiled for x86.

Comment: I know that, but can you elaborate the answer with proper examples and app links. So I can try it out.

Comment: I've used "iso-deploy" to deploy ".app" bundles to both simulator and devices. It's a good tool @amish. https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy

Comment: "iso-deploy" doesn't help me!