# how to integrate whatsapp in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, whatsapp

hi now i am trying Integrate What's app in our app

i have done already integrate Tweet

:-in this app i create two buttons 
one(chooseImagePressed) button is choose the image form local file and then 
and then second(tweetButtonPressed) this is post the image to Tweeter

```
- (IBAction)tweetButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Look at this nice picture!"];

        [tweetSheet addImage:self.imageView.image];

        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:@"please setup Twitter"
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}

- (IBAction)chooseImagePressed:(id)sender
{
    self.pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    self.pickerController.delegate = self;
    self.pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:self.pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark 

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
{
    self.imageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Please give me any idea about the how to integrated what's app into our app

Please tell me this is possible or Not

Thanks

Comment: No this is not possible, whatsapp does not have any public API you can use.

Comment: @iPatel thanks for Reply  what's app install in simulator is possible or Not

Answer (score 4):

**No**, It's not possible `as like tweeter and Facebook api`. But you can send message from your app to whatsapp if whatsapp is already installed as below

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"];//use this method stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding to convert it with escape char
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

But If you want to share document like files, images, video, you've to send it via [UIDocumentInteractionController.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

**Note:** whatsapp should be installed for above two, otherwise you can't do anything as you like. [See this for current whatsApp doc.](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013)

Comment: thanks for Replay What's app install in simulator is possible or Not

Comment: @Vasavi No. It's not possible with simulator.

Comment: @Vasavi - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator

Comment: @Mani now i don't have any iphone

Comment: @Vasavi see iPatel Comment, it may help you.

Answer (score 2):

Simple integration

```
   NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=9530670491&text=hello"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

**Swift**

```
var whatsappURL = URL(string: "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=9530670491&text=hello")
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {
UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL!)
}
```

Also check this link   https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/26000030

Comment: It launches safari if whatsapp is not installed. Is there any way to check if whatsapp is installed ? if not, redirect user to app store.

Answer (score 1):

You will get more inputs here:

http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

-This is used to share any Image/vodeo with WhatsApp.
-You need to do UIDocumentInteractionController Class Reference in your code.
-You need to save the image to disk, and then create a  UIDocumentInteractionController with that file URL.
-Following are the code snaps for the same and you can share image with WhatsApp.

```
  //Path of the image which is present in bundle 
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"images" ofType:@"jpg”];

  /* here you can also give the path of image which is saved on disk.*/


       if (path) {
            NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
            UIDocumentInteractionController* docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
            docController.delegate = self;
            [docController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
        }
```

For text sharing

```
 //This is sharing text encoding with NSUTF8StringEncoding
    NSString* strSharingText = [txtWhatsApp.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //This is whatsApp url working only when you having app in your Apple device
    NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",strSharingText]];

   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this [documented](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/26000030) method:

```
if let urlString = "https://wa.me/\(whatsappPhoneNumber)/?text=Hi. ".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed), 
    let url = URL(string: urlString), 
    UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **For Swift 4.2 and above**

```
let whatsAppURL = URL(string: "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=0123456")

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsAppURL!)
{
    UIApplication.shared.open(whatsAppURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```