# Open whatsapp on iOS with new phone number pre-filled

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp

I know there is scheme to communicate with whatsapp like:

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

But i can't find how to open whatsapp with a phone number that don't exist before.

It's for a "contatc us" page and if i can only open whatsapp and can't pre fill a phone number, it's useless. I need to be contacted with whatsapp...

Does what I am trying to do exist ?

Answer (score 10):

For phone number pre-filled And Text

```
   NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=9530670491&text=hello"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

click here for [Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43653408/4970453)

Check Link For More Details   https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/26000030

Comment: is apple allowed to send message from application

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Whatsapp documentation](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/fr/iphone/23559013), you need to actually have the contact in your address book to open a discussion from the url scheme.
So for your question

> Does what i try to do exist ?

the answer is: **No.**

[image]

Comment: sadly, the abid parameter has dissappeard.  Does anyone know of any alternative to open a contact chat directly from another iOS app?

Comment: @DanielFernandes are you able to find any solution ? , I have found this link https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/26000030

Comment: @MikeAlter, Thanks for the link, however I no longer have any use for Whatsapp integration.   :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the documentation of that whatsapp API above answer. Adding some more point in that based on my own trial :

For communicating direct with the specific contact you need abid of that contact. ABID is that parameter which is automatically generated by the system when you save the contact. So if you dont have number saved in your contact so no way you can open that from your application .

There is one workaround that I have used. When your application load first time in the device , you save the contact us number to the address book . when number saved successfully you will get ABID in the return . you can use that ABID to invoke messaging with that contact.

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?abid=123&text=Hello%2C%20World!"];
```

Comment: "whatsapp://send" method don't work stable for me. For some iOS and WhatsApp version it don't work. I recommend to use "https://wa.me". It works in the same way, opens WhatsApp app.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone looking for Swift version

```
static func triggerWhats(_ vc:UIViewController){
        let msg = "Hello! I have a question"
        let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?phone=+6599999999&text=\(msg)"
        if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed){
            if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
                    _ = UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                    // Cannot open whatsapp
                    ViewUtil().popAlertView(vc, title: "WhatsApp Support", message: "Please WhatsApp us at +65999999 if you have any questions", option: "Ok")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "whatsapp://send" method don't work stable for me. For some iOS and WhatsApp version it don't work. I recommend to use "https://wa.me". It works in the same way, opens WhatsApp app.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0 open whats app.

in **info.plist** file add this line

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
       <string>whatsapp://</string>
</array>

func OpenWhatsApp(_ vc:UIViewController){
        let msg = "" // here pass your message 
        let urlWhats = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=(Mobileno)&text=\(msg)" // Mobile number that include country code and without + sign . 
        if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed){
            if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {
                    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                        _ = UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                    } else {
                        // Fallback on earlier versions
                        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL)
                    }
                } else {
                    // Cannot open whatsapp
                    AppUtilities.sharedInstance.showAlert(title: "WhatsApp Support", msg: "Your device is not support whats app")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSURL` and then casting to URL all the time? You can just declare the URL as `URL`.

Comment: @AndyIbanez yes i can change it wait

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya i have a question i have to open a number in whatsapp whether it is india or foreign then what should i do

Comment: urlwhats app open a chat for particular like in whats app that number Mobile number that include country code and without + sign . is already exist in whats app database.

Answer (score 0):

> For Swift 3.0 OR Above, This will open whatsapp chat of a number
>
> Example of Number: "+918798766554"

```
if let whatappURL = URL(string: "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=\(number)&text=\(msg)"),
  UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatappURL)
{
  if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(whatappURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
  } else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatappURL)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Whatsapp documentation](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/fr/iphone/23559013)

For Swift 3.0 OR Above, This will open whatsapp chat of a number

Example of Number: "+6599999999"

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://wa.me/+6599999999")!)
```