# How to open whats app and viber chat box for a particular number

Tags: ios, whatsapp, viber

within my app I want to send messages to whats app and viber. My app is getting a contact number from the server.when click whats app it should open a chat window for that particular number and send the text defined in my app. I used a url to open but it just open the whats app and viber thats all.

How can I open a chat window specific for a number in ios.
Please help me,
Thnks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202199/open-whatsapp-on-ios-whith-new-phone-number-pre-filled

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541805/launching-viber-app-via-url-scheme-on-ios