# How to make whats app Voice calls from my IOS Application in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp

I am working on the IOS Application to send whatsapp calls from my application.
 I tried for the source to make calls but I got nothing. 
Can any one please suggest me some good source on making whatsapp Voice calls.

But I known that whatsapp not released api to make calls from other apps in IOS.

Comment: you can't make whatsapp voice call from your app. you can just redirect to particular contact number chat thread.

Comment: I know that there is an option to make chat .

Comment: can You provide me the sample on that you suggested solution ?

Comment: check on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44234113/4831524

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: @basha did this worked for you?

Comment: If whatsapp has not released the API means it is prohibited to do. if you find the way to do it then Apple will not approve it since you are using undocumented API.

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly make WhatsApp call from your app. You can redirect to particular contact chat thread using below code:

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?phone=+91ContactNumberHere"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:whatsappURL]) {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:whatsappURL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
} else {

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Whatsapp is not installed on your device." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
    [alert addAction:okAction];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil];
}
```