# Xcode 8 - How can I give the .app file to someone else to test

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an Android developer, who has downloaded XCode. I just want to give him the app file to run in his XCode simulator.

How would I get that to him and how would he "install" it in his iOS simulator?

Comment: ios simulator or device?

Comment: With the latest Xcode 8, just drop the app file on the simulator.

Comment: @GaneshKumar he clearly states simulator

Comment: It is iOS simulator. Where can I go dig up the app file in Xcode 8?

Comment: you can share the code in github or gitlab

Comment: Check something - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator

Comment: i'm not at the point where I want to give my new developer the entire source code...I'm hoping to just deliver the .app file to him.

Comment: Ask him to manage iOS device and give him Diawi URL.

Comment: Just use hockey or testflight and have them install testflight or hockey on the simulator

Comment: or else archive the project and get the **.ipa** file and share that .ipa file

Comment: Dug out the .app file ...zipped it and handed it to him. Was the easiest way to get it to him.  Thanks for all the insight.

Answer (score 0):

These were all good ideas in their own right.

I found the answer here:

https://medium.com/@hollanderbart/new-features-in-xcode-8-2-simulator-fc64a4014a5f#.68c92c2or

This appears to be a new feature in 8.2.